# Equivalence relations regarding binary relations

Tags: discrete-mathematics, solution-verification, equivalence-relations

Let $R \subseteq X \times X$ be a binary relation for $X = \{a, b, c, d\}$.
$R = \{(a, a), (b, c), (c, d), (b, d)\}$. Is the relation an equivalence relation? I don't know if I am proving it correctly by using a formal proof?

Proof:

a)$R \subseteq X \times X$, thus reflexive holds.

b)$R \subseteq X \times X$ then $X \times X \subseteq R$, thus symmetric holds.

c)I don't know how to formally prove it correctly.

Is this correct? Thanks.

Comment: No, mostly wrong. For example, $(b,b),(c,c), (d,d) $ are missing so $R$ is not reflexive.

Comment: What does symmetric mean? If $(b,d) \in R$ then what else must be in $R$?

Comment: @user4894 $(d, b)$.

Comment: Notice also that, since every relation on a set $X$ is a subset of $X \times X$, if your proof was correct, then every relation would reflexive and symmetric.

Answer (score 0):

No, what you have is not correct.

- For $R$ to be **reflexive**, it must contain $(x, x)$ for every $x \in X$.
- For $R$ to be **symmetric**, it must contain $(x, y)$ if it contains $(y, x)$.
- For $R$ to be **transitive**, it must contain $(x, z)$ if it contains $(x, y)$ and $(y, z)$.

In this case, $R$ is not reflexive or symmetric, but it is transitive.

- **Not reflexive:** $R$ does not contain $(b, b)$, $(c, c)$ or $(d, d)$.
- **Not symmetric:** $R$ contains $(b, c)$ but does not contain $(c, b)$.  Similarly, $R$ contains $(c, d)$ but not $(d, c)$ and $(b, d)$ but not $(d, b)$.
- **Transitive:** There is no triple of elements $x, y, z \in X$ such that $R$ contains $(x, y)$ and $(y, z)$ but not $(x, z)$.

---

It might help to think of $R$ as defining a binary operator $\sim$: for each pair of elements $x, y \in X$, $x \sim y$ if and only if $(x, y) \in R$.

- The reflexive property means that every element is related to itself: $x \sim x$ for every $x \in X$.
- The symmetric property means that you can switch the order of the operands: $x \sim y \iff y \sim x$.
- The transitive property means that you can "chain" the relation: $x \sim y \text{ and } y \sim z \implies x \sim z$.

Comment: But the relation is a subset though. So doesn't it have to be subsets between R and X x X?

Comment: @misosoup $R$ is a subset of $X \times X$.  So the elements of $R$ are pairs $(x, y)$ where $x$ and $y$ are elements of $X$.